# Вк-бот отвечает только один раз. Vk_api, python

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType

random_id = vk_api.utils.get_random_id()

def write_msg(user_id, random_id, message):
    vk.method('messages.send', {'user_id': user_id, 'message': message, 'random_id': random_id})

# API-ключ созданный ранее
token = "b0d26aafd417***7527255b2aaee5"

# Авторизуемся как сообщество
vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)

# Работа с сообщениями
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk)

# Основной цикл
for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        print('Новое сообщение')
        request = event.text            
        if request == "привет":
            write_msg(event.user_id, random_id, "Хай")
        elif request == "пока":
            write_msg(event.user_id, random_id, "Пока((")
        else:
            write_msg(event.user_id, random_id, "Не поняла вашего ответа...")
```

После первого ответа, он ничего не делает. Как это исправить?

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте токен не показывал

Comment: random_id должен быть разным для каждого сообщения. В этом его суть

Comment: меняйте random_id в цикле

Comment: @timur как это сделать?

Comment: Походу, достаточно строчку `random_id = vk_api.utils.get_random_id()` перенести в тело цикла.

Answer (score 0):

`random_id` должен быть разным для кажндого сообщения. Это нужно для того, чтобы ваш бот не отравлял одно и то же сообщение несколько раз. При отправке каждого сообщения вы должны генерировать новый `random_id`. Вам нужно в каждом вызове функции `write_msg` указывать `random_id=vk_api.utils.get_random_id()`, например:

```
write_msg(event.user_id, random_id=vk_api.utils.get_random_id(), "Хай")
```

Comment: Тогда уж, лучше строчку `random_id = vk_api.utils.get_random_id()` перенести внутрь цикла, сразу после `for event in longpoll.listen():`

Answer (score 0):

`"random_id" : 0`

И всё. У меня работает как надо